# Create Access file from Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Update : I am almost complete my code, I am trying to export my all excel sheets to access using VB.net.

So far below code, Creates new access file, and imports only one sheet. I want to import all sheets to access. and if there is any duplicates in the field name i want to update the datafield or else create new field.

Here is my code.

```
Dim _filename As String = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.xls"
Dim dbname As String = "D:\Book.mdb"
If File.Exists("D:\Book.mdb") Then
File.Delete("D:\Book.mdb")
End If

Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()
cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=D:\Book.mdb;" & _
"Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
cat = Nothing
 Dim _conn As String
 _conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & _filename & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    Dim _connection As New OleDbConnection(_conn)

    Dim _command As New OleDbCommand()
    _command.Connection = _connection

    _command.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database=D:\Book.mdb].[Sheet1] FROM [Sheet1$]"
    _connection.Open()
    _command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    _connection.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("The import is complete!")
```

Any suggestions

Comment: What have you tried yourself (So we don't supply you with code that you might already have yourself)?

Comment: I'm assuming your getting an error that `Sheet1`does not exist in `book.mdb`?

Comment: No, I have multiple worksheets, the code works only for Sheet1, i want to export all worksheets..

Comment: Then you'll need to iterate each of your worksheets. Shouldn't be to hard using a For-loop.

Comment: In VBA, no issues, but here no idea on that. Any syntax?

Comment: the following link should help you along: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2fce6f8a-7b26-48f6-8efa-08ef9dd05165/new-to-vbnet-how-to-loop-through-worksheets